# What's the quickest & most efficient way of notifying a device that a website has came back online?

Tags: javascript, android, node.js, react-native, express

To determine if the website is online I plan on making a simple ping script and returning a boolean through a REST endpoint or having the phone check periodically for an updated value; but I feel like there has to be a better way. What's the best way to notify the device of a change? Is there a way to make the endpoint send a push notification to a react-native app if the boolean returns true; or a 200 status?

```
const express = require('express')
const domainPing = require('domain-ping')

const port = 4000

const app = express()

cron.schedule("* * * * *", function() {
    domainPing("example.com")
        .then(resp => resp)
            /* 
            * resp: {domain: "example.com", ip: "93.184.216.34", online: true, ping: false, statusCode: 200, success: true}
            * */
            return [resp.online, resp.status] //How can I send a push notification here to react-native?
        .catch(err => {
            console.log(err)
        });
});

app.listen(port, () => console.log(`http://localhost:${port}!`))
```

Comment: Looking around a bit more it looks like FireBase is a good solution to this: https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/js/first-message

Comment: Probably using the push system built into the device platform (iOS or Android) is the most efficient way to send the device a message.  Since your system is down, you can't rely on the usual alternatives (webSocket, SSE, etc...).

Comment: @jfriend00 would it be better to run a standard express app and just have the app check an endpoint? I'll try and lookup how it would work with Web Sockets & SSE as well.